# Prevent the predictive text from learning a set of words

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-5, text-prediction

Is there anyway to prevent the predictive text from learning a set of specified words?

I use a a Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900A) with Android 4.4.2

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.